# How to speed up workflow with database .Net

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework

I have simple controller  that return list of products.It is take about 5-7sec to return the data for the first time,and then 50-80ms ,but only if i run it immediately(10-30sec) after first one ,if i will run it after 2-3min it will be again 5-7s.

I dont store this list in cache,sow i cant understand why only first time it takes 5sec,and then 50ms.

**Important:test that i have made  is not on localhost,it is on the production  server.On localhost it takes 50ms**

How can i speed up?
Do i need to make any change in my code? Or IIS?

My code

```
 public List<PackageModel> GetPromotionOrDefaultPackageList(string domain)
 {
    List<DBProduct> DBPackageList = new List<DBProduct>();
    List<PackageModel> BllPackageList = new List<PackageModel>();
    try
    {
        using (CglDomainEntities _entities = new CglDomainEntities())
        {
            DBPackageList = _entities.DBProducts
                                     .Where(x => 
                             x.ProductGroup.Equals(domain + "-package") 
                             && x.IsPromotionProduct == true)
                                     .ToList();

             if (DBPackageList.Count == 0)
             {
                 DBPackageList = _entities.DBProducts
                                          .Where(x => 
                             x.ProductGroup.Equals(domain + "-package") 
                             && x.IsBasicProduct == true)
                                          .ToList();
             }
         }


         PackageModel bllPackage = new PackageModel();
         foreach (DBProduct dbProduct in DBPackageList)
         {
             bllPackage = new PackageModel();
             bllPackage.Id = dbProduct.Id;
             bllPackage.ProductId = dbProduct.ProductId;
             bllPackage.IsPromotionProduct = dbProduct.IsPromotionProduct.HasValue ? dbProduct.IsPromotionProduct.Value : false;
             bllPackage.ProductName = dbProduct.ProductName;
             bllPackage.ProductDescription = dbProduct.ProductDescription;
             bllPackage.Price = dbProduct.Price;
             bllPackage.Currency = dbProduct.Currency;
             bllPackage.CampaignId = dbProduct.CampaignId;
             bllPackage.PathToProductImage = dbProduct.PathToProductImage;
             bllPackage.PathToProductPromotionImage = dbProduct.PathToProductPromotionImage;
             bllPackage.PathToProductInfo = dbProduct.PathToProductInfo;
             bllPackage.CssClass = dbProduct.CssClass;
             BllPackageList.Add(bllPackage);
         }

         return BllPackageList;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Logger.Error(ex.Message);
         return BllPackageList;
     }
}
```

Comment: For development use database with less amount of rows.

Comment: i have 25 rows,is it too much?

Comment: 25 rows shouldn't be a problem, the code you shown is simple enough, you should look from somewhere else. Are you using local database or external, does UI doing something else. Try eliminate possible bottlenecks one by one

Comment: external,UI just make request to this controller and wait for list of products.In console log (network) i see that my request is taking about 5-7 seconds,when i run it  first time ,and after then in 100ms

Comment: 5 seconds for 25 rows means the query is *extremely* inefficient and uses no indexes. Tables with 1M rows is *small* data these days. Single-server databases can handle TBs of data.

Comment: Is `ProductGroup` indexed? Indexing that field should speed up the query. Indexing `IsPromotionProduct` or `IsBasicProduct` won't help all that much as those columns have very low selectivity - half of the table rows will have one value or the other, so the server could just scan all rows.

Comment: Another problem is that `ToList()` loads the entire row in each case instead of just the columns needed by `PackageModel`. You could use `Select(product=>new PackageModel{ Id=product.Id,....}).ToList()` to have EF load only the necessary columns *and* produce the models in a single operation

Comment: Yes they are indexed.i will try,but i wasn't exactly clear about my problem,only first request takes 5sec ,second one 50ms, if i call it aftet 2-3min it again will take 5 sec and not 50ms. Check my updated question

Comment: @VovaPotapov that's *far too slow* for just 25 rows. In any case database servers *always* cache data, that's their job. They don't remove rows from their buffers either, unless there's memory pressure. It's impossible to help more though without the table creation script (including the indexes) and the execution plan. Perhaps the indexes aren't suitable for this query, resulting it table scans instead of index seeks. Perhaps the table is too wide and `ToList()` loads eg 100 columns instead of 10.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos  The  table is very simple,25 columns and about 250 rows that nothing for data base as you know.I thinking maybe problem in cloud-flare or IIS setting,i really dont know.

Comment: *Cloud*? What exactly do you mean? How is the site deployed, is it even a *site* or a serverless function that closes after 5 minutes? Deployment matters. If you deploy on IIS on a local server you get better performance simply because the server is always on - assuming you haven't set a *very* short idle timeout. Hosters though like to cram as many sites as possible on the same machines, so they set very tight timeouts *and* overprovision the servers: they deploy more sites than the server could handle if *all* of them run at the same time.